# Sorting a dataframe by substring of columns values

Tags: r, regex, sorting

Been trying to find the answer to this question and haven't been able to. Say I have the dataframe,

```
DF <- data.frame (x=c("2,A","1,A","1,C", "1,B"), y = c(1,2,2,1))
```

yielding a Dataframe with two columns, the first of which has a number and a letter. 
How can I sort DF according to the number part of each of its rows? And then, add to it another column only with the letter. The objective is to obtain,

```
    x y z
1 1,A 2 A
2 2,A 1 A
3 1,B 1 B
4 1,C 2 C
```

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `gsub` to replace all digits or comma (`"(\\d+|,)"`) and all non-digits (`"\\D+"`) successively and then use `order` to sort `DF` based on that.

```
DF = DF[order(as.character(gsub("(\\d+|,)", "", DF$x)), as.numeric(gsub("\\D+", "", DF$x))),]
DF$z = gsub("(\\d+|,)", "", DF$x)
DF
#    x y z
#2 1,A 2 A
#1 2,A 1 A
#4 1,B 1 B
#3 1,C 2 C
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks for the answer and the general tip on handling digits and strings! :)